# Как добавить картинку в галерею эмулятор андроид?

Tags: android, gallery

Как добавить картинку в галерею эмулятор андроид?

Comment: Добавить откуда?

Comment: С рабочего стола Windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавить файл с компьютера на устройство можно с помощью `ADB`:

```
adb push <file-source-local> <destination-path-remote>
```

где:

- `<file-source-local>` – путь до файла на компьютере;
- `<destination-path-remote>` – путь до папки на устройстве.

Так же это можно [осуществить с помощью `DDMS`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37860254):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Огромное спасибо!!!

Comment: Как узнать <destination-path-remote>?

Comment: во втором варианте в папку sdcard невозможно добавить что либо изза отсутствия прав. Что делать?